# update table sql based on two criterias

Tags: sql

Ok so I have seen a few posts on this but for some reason my code doesn't update the TrnID field from table A with the information on LastTrnID from table B, any help will be greatly appreciated. If I base my inner join on just one field then the update works, however I know it can be done so that you inner join on two fields but I can only assume that I am not doing it correctly. Basically table A and table B are created on the fly at the beginning of the query and then I have to put both sets into one table. The final table should include the person and then for each person the first and last transaction per day which is why I am doing inner join on CrdID and LastTrnDate which is the day portion of the field.

```
UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.TrnID = Table_B.LastTrnID       
FROM Table_A
INNER JOIN Table_B 
        ON (Table_A.CrdID = Table_B.CardholderID) 
       AND (Table_A.TrnD = Table_B.LastTrnDate)
```

Comment: We need db schema, sample data and expected output. Are you executing this direct on db or in your application? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: more likely Table_A.TrnD and Table_B.LastTrnDate will never be equal due tot eh time part of the transaction. use instead:   CONVERT(varchar, Table_A.TrnD, 101) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, Table_B.LastTrnDate, 101)

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks OK (beside the extra # on #Table_A)

So probably is error on the data. First check your query is bringing the results

Try this `SELECT` to see if the fields you want update and the new value are correct.

```
SELECT Table_A.TrnID, Table_B.LastTrnID       
FROM Table_A 
INNER JOIN Table_B 
        ON Table_A.CrdID = Table_B.CardholderID
       AND Table_A.TrnD  = Table_B.LastTrnDate
```

Comment: I apologize, the extra # was just a typo here on the site. Pretty much what I am trying to do is update a field on table A, based on two criteria. As of right now the field from table A will only get updated if I have only one criteria on my inner join. If I add the second one criteria then the update no longer works.

Comment: did you try the select? give you any result?

Answer (score 0):

```
  UPDATE f1
  SET f1.TrnID = f2.LastTrnID       
  FROM Table_A f1 INNER JOIN Table_B f2 
    ON (f1.CrdID = f2.CardholderID) AND (f1.TrnD = f2.LastTrnDate)
```